# node.js mongo db write concern

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am running node.js 10.22, windows 8 and mongodb not sure what version, but I just downloaded it today, when I run my code I am getting a message, please ensure you set the default write concern, I am trying to follow a YouTube video, and there is mention of this, and I am finding little about it on the internet, from what i found, when I set the db i should set j:true, or safe : true/false, but neither not working for me. I do get the console log that I'm connected and the host and port, but then I get the write concern message and can't type or do anything.

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var host = "127.0.0.1";
var port = mongo.Connection.DEFAULT_PORT;

var db = new mongo.Db("nodeintro", new mongo.Server(host,port,{Fsync: true}));
db.open(function(error){
  console.log("we are connected"+host + port);
})
```

Tried this all type of ways as well, still no luck, best i did was get back to the db write concern message, but was not able to even connect this time. What I'm really looking for is to be able to insert anything in mongo db, and i can figure out the rest.

```
var Db = require('mongodb').Db;
var Connection = require('mongodb').Connection;
var Server = require('mongodb').Server;
var BSON = require('mongodb').BSON;
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var host = "127.0.0.1";
var port = mongo.DEFAULT_PORT;


ArticleProvider = function(host, port) {
this.db= new Db('node-mongo-blog', new Server(host, port, {auto_reconnect: true}, {}));
this.db.open(function(error){
if(error){
console.log(error)
}
else{
console.log(port,host)
}

});
};
ArticleProvider(host,port)
```

Comment: I'd say ditch mongodb-native and go for Mongoose. Much nicer coding style, and handles all the boilerplate non-sense.

Comment: @ tsturzl Thanks for the advice, I just started learning so I very well might do that!

Answer (score 0):

When using `mongodb-native` directly, you should now use [`MongoClient.connect`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/mongoclient.html#mongoclient-connect) to open a database connection pool.  It will set a default write concern for you.

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
mongodb.MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/nodeintro', function(err, db) {
    // db is your open nodeintro database connection pool here
});
```

`MongoClient` was a somewhat recent addition so the tutorial you're working from likely pre-dates it.

Comment: thank you! can you put the full answer so I can copy and paste it, Im not swift enough to put it together. I would put what i tried from your answer, but i'm afraid im going to get yelled at for puting code or something.

Comment: @user3081020 All I left off the was the `require` statement, which I just added.

Comment: Thanks for trying, I'm sure it works but it's not working for me, I'm probably newer at this then you think. if i add a if statement with console log, err or else connected, i get error. And after that i can't type anything in the command prompt.

Comment: @user3081020 No worries, we all started where you are now.  What's the error that you get?  The first thing people usually trip over on Windows is that they're not not actually running the MongoDB server.

Comment: console.log for db is = null and for error failed to connect to local host [27017] does that mean it's not getting the 127.0.0.1?

Comment: @user3081020 Sounds like you're not running the server.  See here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/

Comment: when i access it, it's through  C:/users/phill> node nameoffile.js

Comment: I don't think i am, there does not look like there is anything in your code that does run the server, i running what u gave me.

Comment: with what I had I was connecting, but getting the write concern page too.

Answer (score 0):

If you use {w:1} parameter in your insert or update operation, you might give this error. To overcome you can use {journal:true} parameter in your db settings.

### For instance;

```
var Db = require('mongodb').Db,
MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
Server = require('mongodb').Server,
ReplSetServers = require('mongodb').ReplSetServers,
ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID,
Binary = require('mongodb').Binary,
GridStore = require('mongodb').GridStore,
Grid = require('mongodb').Grid,
Code = require('mongodb').Code,
BSON = require('mongodb').pure().BSON;

var db = new Db('Your DB Name', new Server('192.168.170.128', 27017), { journal : true });

db.open(function(err, db) {

    var collection = db.collection('user');

    collection.findOne({'_id':req.session.User._id}, function(err, user){

        // some codes what do you want
        collection.save( user, {w: 1}, function(err, user_id) {

           // just close the db connection
           db.close(); 

        });
    });
});
```